# How Using UTF ( Persian Language ) in Bracket?

Tags: adobe-brackets, brackets-shell

When i Using The Persian (UTF) in Bracket Show Me Like This .

This My Text in Bracket :

```
<h1>سلام این ایت منه</h1>
```

This Show Me in google Chrome

```
Ø³Ù„Ø§Ù… Ø§ÛŒÙ† Ø§ÛŒØª Ù…Ù†Ù‡
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line inside your html `<head></head>` tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```